# Refactoring IEnumerable<ValidationResult>

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc

I have the below code which increases the code complexity. Any way to refactor it?

I am trying to refactor the below code so that the CCM can be reduced for the code. i.e code complexity matrix.

```
//// TODO: Needs refactoring
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var memberNames = new List<string>();

        if (this.DateOfBirth == DateTime.MaxValue)
        {
            memberNames.Add("DateOfBirth");
            yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid date, please enter your date of birth", memberNames);
        }
        else if (this.DateOfBirth == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            memberNames.Add("DateOfBirth");
            yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid date, please enter your date of birth", memberNames);
        }

        if (!this.Age.HasValue)
        {
            memberNames.Add("DateOfBirth");
            yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid date, please enter your date of birth", memberNames);
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.Age < 18 || this.Age > 75)
            {
                memberNames.Add("DateOfBirth");
                yield return new ValidationResult("Age must be between 18 and 75 years", memberNames);
            }
        }

        if (!this.Gender.HasValue)
        {
            memberNames.Add("Gender");
            yield return new ValidationResult("This field is required", memberNames);
        }

        if (!(this.Age >= 60))
        {
            yield break;
        }

        // similarly many more validation checks - if-else conditions
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the other conditions but I would do it like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var memberNames = new List<string>();

    bool isValidDateOfBirth = DateOfBirth > DateTime.MinValue && DateOfBirth < DateTime.MaxValue && Age.HasValue;
    if (!isValidDateOfBirth)
    {
        memberNames.Add("DateOfBirth");
        yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid date, please enter your date of birth", memberNames);
    }

    bool isValidAge = Age.HasValue && Age.Value >= 18 && Age <= 75;
    if (!isValidAge)
    {
        memberNames.Add("DateOfBirth");
        yield return new ValidationResult("Age must be between 18 and 75 years", memberNames);
    }

    bool isValidGender = Gender.HasValue;
    if (!isValidGender)
    {
        memberNames.Add("Gender");
        yield return new ValidationResult("This field is required", memberNames);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer did a nice job of refactoring your code, but there are other things that can be said about it.

To begin with, I'm not sure you're doing a great job of validating `BirthDate`.

> ```
> if (this.DateOfBirth == DateTime.MinValue)
> ```

and

> ```
> if (this.DateOfBirth == DateTime.MaxValue)
> ```

What's wrong with this? Well.... nothing. As far as *the computer* is concerned. However, I'm afraid these values don't make much sense in the real world.

> The value of this constant is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001.
>
> [*MDSN - DateTime.MinValue*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The value of this constant is equivalent to 23:59:59.9999999, December 31, 9999, exactly one 100-nanosecond tick before 00:00:00, January 1, 10000.
>
> [*MSDN - DateTime.MaxValue*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, essentially, you're allowing a wide swath of dates that probably shouldn't be allowed. How could someone be born *almost eight thousand years in the future*?

Now, if you do this validation properly right there, then this snippet becomes completely irrelevant and can be removed.

> ```
>     else
>     {
>         if (this.Age < 18 || this.Age > 75)
>         {
>             memberNames.Add("DateOfBirth");
>             yield return new ValidationResult("Age must be between 18 and 75 years", memberNames);
>         }
>     }
> ```